# Update two different rows in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here My table looks like in MS-SQL

```
ID   Name   Mark1    Mark2    Grade
1    ABC    50       75       A+
2    XYZ    0        15       A+
3    XYZ    20       0        B+
```

I need the result should be like:-

```
ID   Name   Mark1    Mark2
1    ABC    50       75
2    XYZ    20       15
```

If ID, Name are matches i need to display the Mark1 & Mark2 value
in a single row but there grade is different like the same i have to update
multiple rows please help on this.

Note:- Grade is not required in the final result set and 3rd row is not required once values get updated we need to remove the 3rd row.

Here I have added:-

Input:-

```
ID   Name   Mark1    Mark2    Grade

1    ABC    50       75       A+

2    XYZ    0        15       A+

3    XYZ    20       0        B+

4         ZZZ         30                0                   B+

4         ZZZ          40                0                   B+

4         ZZZ         50                0                   B+
```

Output:-

```
ID   Name   Mark1    Mark2    Grade

1    ABC    50       75       A+

2    XYZ    20       15       A+

4    ZZZ       30                0                   B+

4    ZZZ         40                0                   B+

4    ZZZ         50                0                   B+
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply done with a group by and MAX function :

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, Name, MAX(Mark1), MAX(Mark2)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: It's fine but there is an exception for the Id we do have multiple entries it's affecting that too.                                                                              ID   Name   Mark1    Mark2    Grade
1    ABC    50       75       A+
2    XYZ    0        15       A+
3    XYZ    20       0        B+
4         XYZ         30                0                   B+
4         XYZ         40                0                   B+
4         XYZ         50                0                   B+

Comment: The list of records which i has it's in crores so it will impact in many places.

Comment: @Ramesh what is the output of this example?

Comment: Input:- ID   Name   Mark1    Mark2    Grade
1    ABC    50       75       A+
2    XYZ    0        15       A+
3    XYZ    20       0        B+
4         ZZZ         30                0                   B+
4         ZZZ          40                0                   B+
4         ZZZ         50                0                   B+

Comment: I have added in above post